# Matlab, fimplicit, how to show a specified region on graph using an inequality

Tags: charts, matlab

I am using fimplicit command to produce a graph, but i have a condition x+y<=1, and I want only that region of the graph to be shown.

Example:
f = @(x,y) x.^2 + y.^2 - 3;
fimplicit(f,[-3 3 -2 2])

If there is no such option within fimplicit, I am also open for the suggestions to modify the figure after plotting fimplicit.
PS. Of course my function is not the one above, it is much complicated, so I thought it would be useful to use a simple example here in this post. By the way simply changing -3 and -2 to 0 and 3 and 2 to 1 wont work on my original function. Alternatively, what will work with my case is to paint the graph to white for the parts that I do not what to be visible such as x+y>=1, but I donot know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem, using patch command, 
I simply draw a poligon for the areas that I do not want to be visible, then select the fill colour as white.
Below, I draw a triangle for the values where x+y higher than 1, and fill them white.

v = [0 1; 1 0; 1 1];
f = [1 2 3];
patch('Faces',f,'Vertices',v,'FaceColor','white')